# How to increase display resolution in QEMU/KVM via virt-manager on Manjaro (host/guest)?

Tags: arch-linux, qemu, linux-kvm, manjaro

How to increase the guest's resolution in QEMU/KVM?

Currently, I am only able to reach a max resolution of `1280x720` on my guest virtual machine; however, I would like to increase it to `1980x1080` to match my host's resolution.

I have **Manjaro 18.0.4** running on both my host and on my guest. Here are the steps I followed to setup the system:

#### On the host OS

```bsh
sudo pacman -Syu
sudo pacman -S virt-manager qemu vde2 ebtables dnsmasq bridge-utils openbsd-netcat
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd.service
sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service
```

Then I created a new virtual machine using `virt-manager` as follows:

- **Display server**: Spice server + default options
- **Video**: QXL + `vgamem="32768"`
- **View > Scale Display**: Never + Autoresize VM with windows (this option probably are irrelevant to the problem)

#### On the guest OS

```bsh
sudo pacman -S spice-vdagent xf86-video-qxl
```

However the max resolution available is still `1280x720`. I would like make changes within `virt-manager` if possible.

P.S.1: The **Scale Display** options work but that is not what I want to achieve as the scaled graphics aren't great.

P.S.2: I would like to keep with Spice/QXL setup as it seems better than VGA

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related to **Manjaro** running as the guest OS.

The solution is to remove the default *xorg* configuration in *90-mhwd.conf* on the guest OS as posted in this [forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-stuck-at-1280x720-in-unraid-kvm-virtual-machine/39236/3):

```bsh
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-mhwd.conf
```